# Boot Camp partition not even starting to boot

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

I do not remember doing anything unusual to my Mac, but when I tried rebooting into Windows partition, nothing happened. If I didn't hold alt while booting, I got white screen stuck for ages. If I held alt and picked Windows partition manually, OS selection screen would become frozen. Apparently, since my BC partition is NTFS, I am unable to check it, but Boot Camp virtual machine works just fine for some reason. What is wrong, and how can I fix it without doing a reinstall?

Comment: Make sure you Shut Down the VM, not just suspend it, otherwise the Boot Camp doesn't work.

Comment: For some weird reason removing external HDD (exFat, not bootable) and hub with plugged in: printer, disconnected micro-usb cable and gaming gadget (razor nostromo) everything started working. I will try to investigate the issue, and post an answer only when I discover the reason.

Comment: OK, the problem is localised to Razer Nostromo gadget.